# Error registration server

Tags: logging

We are planing standalone application-error registration server for our new project. Requirements:
 - High availability
 - Simple and powerfull ui (filters, error groups)
 - Error registration via HTTP

Does anybody know one?

Comment: error registration as in error logging? what server do you have in mind?

Comment: something that could take error entry using http, store it and display error logs to administrator